# Web "touchstart" event listener does not create TouchEvent in same location as another from separate browser window

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, touch-event

**Background and Problem**

I am currently working on a project that consists of 2 browser windows that are being interacted with on 2 separate touch-enabled displays.  I am running into the problem that the eventlistener for "touchstart" will not create a new touch event in the same location as a previous one even though these two touches are inside of different windows (ex: (100,100) on each screen, the touch on the second browser window will not be registered at all because there is already one at (100,100) even though it is in a different browser window).

**What I've Tested**

- I have also confirmed that the touch identifiers for the two touches are different, meaning that the touch events are pooled together somewhere lower and checked before creating a new one.
- Touching in two different locations (ex: 100,100 vs 300,300) will register a touch in each location, therefore the issue is not related to there being one master pointer as I have some complicated master pointer stuff set up that allows multiple master pointers but I will spare you those details.
- There also seems to be a radius around a touch that does not create a new one, even if the second touch is not in the exact same position as the first, the touchstart event is not fired.

**My Assumption**

It seems to me that when a new touch happens, the touchevent pool is checked and confirms that a new one is able to be made and creates it with identifier of n+1.  While this is happening, I assume there is a check somewhere that looks at the positions of all current touches and then doesn't create a new one that is very close to an existing touch.

**Expected Function**

I am looking for a way to get 2 touchstart events to fire even though they are in the "same" location. Ex: I touch (100,100) with one finger then touch that same spot, I want a touchstart event to fire for each touch

Comment: I've been struggling with this issue as well. I've confirmed that Chrome and Firefox handles this different so it must not be well defined in the browser spec. Chrome just ignores touches on the second display while Firefox takes control from the first display to second display.

Comment: @TylerTracy I saw the same thing as well. I also tested with 1 firefox window and 1 chrome window and the touch events fired just fine. Leads me to believe its the underlying implementation of the touch events and under which conditions they each decide to fire them